# Filter time series data frame in Pandas to give first datapoint in every minute

Tags: python, pandas

I have high frequency FX data that has multiple data points every minute. 
For my analysis I am happy with 1 data point per minute.

Hence I need to pick the first data point in every minute and keep it; and discard the other data points in the same minute.

I have a sample data set and expected outcome in the attached image. [image: fx dataset and expected outcome]

Code to create the dataset is below.

```
 import pandas as pd

date_time = ['20120201 170005600', '20120201 170035600', '20120201 170058600', '20120201 170105600',
             '20120201 170135600', '20120201 170158600', '20120201 170205600', '20120201 170235600',
             '20120201 170258600', '20120201 170305600', '20120201 170335600', '20120201 170358600', 
             '20120201 170405600', '20120201 170435600', '20120201 170458600']

bid = [1.306600, 1.306700, 1.306800, 1.306900, 1.307000, 1.307100, 1.307200, 1.307300, 
       1.307400,1.307500, 1.307600, 1.307700, 1.307800, 1.307900, 1.308000]
ask =[1.306770, 1.306870, 1.306970, 1.307070, 1.307170, 1.307270, 1.307370, 1.307470, 
      1.307570, 1.307670, 1.307770, 1.307870, 1.307970, 1.308070, 1.308170]


df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':date_time, 'bid':bid, 'ask':ask})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), s possible change frequency by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S%f')

df1 = df.set_index('date_time').asfreq('T')
print (df1)
                            bid      ask
date_time                               
2012-02-01 17:00:05.600  1.3066  1.30677
2012-02-01 17:01:05.600  1.3069  1.30707
2012-02-01 17:02:05.600  1.3072  1.30737
2012-02-01 17:03:05.600  1.3075  1.30767
2012-02-01 17:04:05.600  1.3078  1.30797
```

Or use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `first`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('date_time').resample('T').first()
```